# Is there a way to subclass UIToolbar?

Tags: ios, xcode, global, uitoolbar, nsobject

I ask this as I would like a global toolbar in my app (similar to the Facebook app with buttons on it). How do I subclass it so that I can add it on all of my ViewControllers? I've created a new class but UIToolbar isn't in the options. How would I modify NSObject manually?

Edit:

My controller hierarchy is as follows:

A login page, which pushes (flip horizontal) -----> Tab Bar Controller. How would I add this toolbar to the top of each page in the tab bar controller?

Comment: It's not in the options but you can type it in.

Comment: I typed in UIToolbar, and it created the class. I've set the toolbar to use this class in storyboard but I can't drag and drop outlets/actions from the buttons in the UIToolbar to the custom UIToolbar class. Only the view controller that the toolbar resides in. Any ideas?

Comment: You can subclass anything, though Xcode might not have it in the auto completion index.

Comment: Why do you think you need to subclass `UIToolbar`?

Comment: @robmayoff how else would I do it? What would be the best way?

Comment: Just use a `UIToolbar`.  There is something that you want to do, and you don't know how to do it with a standard `UIToolbar`.  Tell us what it is.

Comment: I want the same UIToolbar in multiple view controllers throughout the app. A sort of 'global' toolbar. I'm obviously looking at doing it the wrong way. How would you suggest to do it without writing the same code in each view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a `UINavigationController` as your window's root view controller, you can let the navigation controller display a toolbar.  You need to tell it to show the toolbar by sending it a `setToolbarHidden:animated:` message.  If you want the toolbar to have the same buttons (or other subviews) in all your view controllers, make sure you set each view controller's `toolbarItems` property to the same array of items.

If you are not using a `UINavigationController` as your window's root view controller, edit your question and describe your view controller hierarchy.

Comment: I've edited the original question. Thanks for all of your help so far!